# Insert Custom Page in PageView.builder in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am using PageView.builder widget and I want to insert a custom page after each 5 pageviews.

```
return PageView.builder(
  itemCount: 50,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0)
      return Column(
        children: [
          customImage(),   // this will be my custom pageview
          Image.network(_newList[index].image),
        ],
      );
    else
      return Image.network(_newList[index].image);
  },
);
```

The above code is working fine, but it is replacing the image of index 5 and displaying my custom page.

so please help me how can I display customImage without losing any index data.

Comment: `Image.network(_newList[index - index ~/ 5].image)` or something like that

Comment: not working, can you provide any other solution

Comment: I am losing index = 5 data

Comment: no, you are not loosing: `child: PageView.builder(
itemCount: 50,
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
return FittedBox(
child: i % 5 == 0 && i != 0 ?
FlutterLogo() :
Text('${i - i ~/ 5}')
);
}
),` - basically you have to skip `i ~/ 5` elements and it is done with `i - i ~/ 5`

Comment: I am losing data, itemCount is 50, which means I had to get index 0 to 49, but I am getting up to 40, why?

Comment: because you have to increase `itemCount` by a number of your "custom pages" that are inserted every 5th page

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase your `itemcount`

```
int modular = 5;
int count = 50;
int i = 0;
int itemCount = count + modular;

return PageView.builder(
  itemCount: itemCount,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index % modular == 0 && index != 0)
      return Column(
        children: [
          customImage(),
          Image.network(_newList[index].image),
        ],
      );
    else {
     Widget yourImage = Image.network(_newList[i].image);
     i = index + 1;
     return yourImage;
    }
  },
);
```